# Libssh - SSH MESSAGE Unimplemented

Tags: c, networking, ssh

I'm trying to connect using ssh_connect and libssh, but i get the following error. I have no idea what it means. Any thoughts?

```
[2014/09/30 00:53:00.015877, 2] channel_open:  Creating a channel 43 with 64000 window and 32768 max packet
[2014/09/30 00:53:00.050776, 1] ssh_packet_unimplemented:  Received SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED (sequence number 3)
[2014/09/30 00:54:59.949316, 1] ssh_socket_exception_callback:  Socket exception callback: 1 (0)
[2014/09/30 00:54:59.949483, 1] ssh_socket_exception_callback:  Socket error: disconnected
Error allocating SFTP session: Socket error: disconnected
```

here's the code

```
** Initialises SSH Session **/ 
ssh_session initialise_ssh(char* host, int port) {

  ssh_session my_ssh_session;
  int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;

  my_ssh_session = ssh_new();

  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host);
  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
  ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

  rc = ssh_connect(current_session);
  if (rc != SSH_OK)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting host: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(current_session));

  return my_ssh_session; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssh_session object you create in your initialise_ssh() function is not completely initialized yet and thus cannot directly be used to create an sftp session like you try to do. It is laking some authentication and thus the socket is closed after a timeout of 120 seconds, yealding your exception.

After your successful ssh_connect() call you *should* authenticate the host (ssh_is_server_known() function among others) and you *must* provide a way to authenticate the user: a ssh_userauth_publickey_auto(my_ssh_session, NULL, NULL) would do it if you have public key login set up for the user running your app.

Check "Authenticating the server" and "Authenticating the user" in http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html

After that you are set up to use your session to do some work, do some sftp in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating my_ssh_session inside the function. Its scope is limited to the function initialise_ssh. Instead use pointers, or send the session object to be initialized as a parameter.

```
void initialise_ssh(char* host, int port, session* my_ssh_session_ptr) {

  int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;

  *my_ssh_session_ptr = ssh_new();

  ssh_options_set(*my_ssh_session_ptr, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host);
  ssh_options_set(*my_ssh_session_ptr, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
  ssh_options_set(*my_ssh_session_ptr, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

  rc = ssh_connect(current_session);
  if (rc != SSH_OK)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting host: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(current_session));


}
```

Comment: Try adding an example. As it is, your answer is fairly unhelpful as it could be interpreted in several ways

Comment: ssh_session is already a pointer type, so its scope is not limited to the initialise_ssh function.