# SSH execute commands remotely

Tags: c, networking, ssh, packets, libssh

I am trying to ssh to a remote server and execute a simple command. Using the libssh library and the following code,

```
ssh_key pKey;
ssh_session session;
ssh_channel channel;
int rc = ssh_pki_import_privkey_file(PC_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pKey);
char buffer[1024];
unsigned int nbytes;

printf("Session...\n");
session = ssh_new();
if (session == NULL) exit(-1);

ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, PC_HOST);
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, PC_USER);
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &PC_PORT);
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &PC_VERBOSITY);

printf("Connecting...\n");
rc = ssh_connect(session);
if (rc != SSH_OK) error(session);

printf("Channel...\n");
channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
if (channel == NULL) exit(-1);

printf("Opening...\n");
rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
if (rc != SSH_OK) error(session);

printf("Executing remote command...\n");
rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "ls -l");
if (rc != SSH_OK) error(session);

printf("Received:\n");
nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
while (nbytes > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, nbytes, stdout);
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}
```

The ssh connect works successfully, but when it gets to the section of the code which creates the channel and executes the command I get these messages:

```
channel_open:  Creating a channel 43 with 64000 window and 32768 max packet
packet_send2:  packet: wrote [len=44,padding=19,comp=24,payload=24]
channel_open:  Sent a SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN type session for channel 43
ssh_socket_unbuffered_write:  Enabling POLLOUT for socket
ssh_packet_socket_callback:  packet: read type 3 [len=12,padding=6,comp=5,payload=5]
ssh_packet_process:  Dispatching handler for packet type 3
ssh_packet_unimplemented:  Received SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED (sequence number 3)
```

I did some researching and found a [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1013015/i-keep-on-getting-a-error-when-i-connect-to-a-ssh-tunnel-on-putty) that is similar to the issue I'm having, but was confused by the top answer of the question. Also, a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113690/libssh-ssh-message-unimplemented), but does not have a solution to my problem.

I'm not sure how to resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated.